# kernel of $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/n$ is $\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Does any group homomorphism $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/n$ have kernel isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$?

Here $n$ is any natural number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In fact any non-injective group homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to G$ has kernel ispmorphic to $\Bbb Z$.
The rason is that the only non-trivial subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ are $m\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Any map $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/n$ cannot be injective and so $\ker f\neq0$. Recall that $\ker f\le\Bbb Z$ and any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Now conclude that $\ker f$ must be infinite cyclic because $\Bbb Z$ has no elements of finite order.